# how to implement a price range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing a range slider within the bootstrap template:

```html
<input type="range" name="range" step="50000" min="100000" max="1000000" value="" onchange="rangePrimary.value=value">
<input type="text" id="rangePrimary" />
```

The range value is displayed in the text-field with id `rangeprimary`.

I want to make this range slider work as a price range slider, where the lowest and highest ranges would be passed into two text-fields

Most of the price range sliders I have seen don't work well with the template am using.

Comment: so you want the max and min values of a slider to be changable by a input

Comment: no, i want two sliders on my my range field one displaying the min and the other displaying max figures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ion Range Slider is an excellent option, requiring only Jquery.
Very customizable and works excellently in Bootstrap. Also has excellent documentation.

http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html

An example of a single slider implementing exactly what you require using this plugin is shown on the Basic Demo Page.

```
<input type="text" id="rangePrimary" name="rangePrimary" value="" />
<p id="priceRangeSelected"></P>

$("#rangePrimary").ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    grid: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    from: 200,
    to: 800,
    prefix: "£"
});
```

To then get the data from it you can do an Onchange Function example again from the web site.

```
$("#rangePrimary").on("change", function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        value = $this.prop("value").split(";");
        var minPrice = value[0];
        var maxPrice = value[1];
        $("#priceRangeSelected").text("Lower Price Range = £" + minPrice + " , Upper Price Range = £" + maxPrice);
});
```

This will update produce a message below the slider with the value selected on change of the sliders.

Comment: thanks, bt am really nt gud at javascript, i just coppy and use, can u do a full example with the textfiels for min and max please

Comment: @Tee Famakin  I have added a text block to show the values returned from the slider. I really do recommend that you check out the link for the range slider there is a full working demo of exactly what you are requiring with excellent documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to a price slider range.

1)[Price Slider Shopping Carts](https://codepen.io/vtechguys/pen/YeKXmx)(Visit this link)

HTML

```
   <div id="rangeBox">    
         <div id="sliderBox">
             <input type="range" id="slider0to50" step="5" min="0" max="50">
             <input type="range" id="slider51to100" step="5" min="50" max="100">
         </div>
         <div id="inputRange">
             <input type="number" step="5" min="0" max="50" placeholder="Min" id="min" >
             <input type="number" step="5" min="51" max="100" placeholder="Max" id="max">
         </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#rangeBox{ /* carry complete  range box*/
    width:300px;
    height:100px;

    }
    #sliderBox{
    position:relative;
    top:0%;
    width:300px;  /*2x width*/
    }
    #slider0to50{
    width:150px;/*1x width*/
    position:absolute;
    left:0%;
    }
    #slider51to100{
    width:150px;/*1x width*/
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    }
    #inputRange{
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    }
    #inputRange::after{
    content:"";
    clear:both;
    display:block
    }
    #inputRange #min{
     width:40%;
    float:left;
     }   
    #inputRange #max{
     width:40%;
    float:right;
    }
```

JS

```
var sliderLeft=document.getElementById("slider0to50");
 var sliderRight=document.getElementById("slider51to100");
 var inputMin=document.getElementById("min");
 var inputMax=document.getElementById("max");

///value updation from input to slider
//function input update to slider
function sliderLeftInput(){//input udate slider left
    sliderLeft.value=inputMin.value;
}
function sliderRightInput(){//input update slider right
    sliderRight.value=(inputMax.value);//chnage in input max updated in slider right
}

//calling function on change of inputs to update in slider
inputMin.addEventListener("change",sliderLeftInput);
inputMax.addEventListener("change",sliderRightInput);


///value updation from slider to input
//functions to update from slider to inputs 
function inputMinSliderLeft(){//slider update inputs
    inputMin.value=sliderLeft.value;
}
function inputMaxSliderRight(){//slider update inputs
    inputMax.value=sliderRight.value;
}
sliderLeft.addEventListener("change",inputMinSliderLeft);
sliderRight.addEventListener("change",inputMaxSliderRight);
```

2)[Multiple Thumb Slider Shopping Carts Advance](https://codepen.io/vtechguys/pen/MQgKov)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element from javascript and then give it the properties min and max getting them from the two textfields:

```
var x = document.getElementById('rangePrimary');
x.min = the value you get from the first textfield
x.max = the value you
```

Comment: am nt that good wif javascript can u shw an implemnetation so that there wud be two sliders on the range and they both work for min and max